# Declaring variable within 'while loop' but can't change value during loop

Tags: c#, variables, loops, while-loop, scope

I'm trying to make this loop work so it will keep asking for a number until the user enters 999. However with this version of code, it won't build saying I can't declare num within the loop becuase I'm giving it different meaning in this scope.

The try and catch are used because of my assignment rules for this piece of code.

```
int num;
while (num != 999)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a number between 0 and 99");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    try
    {
        int num = Convert.ToInt32(input);
        Console.WriteLine("This is element number " + num + " : " + randNums[num]);
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Data inputted is not between 0 and 99");
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("You chose the secret value, well done!");
```

Comment: Just remove the `int` from in front of the second `num`

Comment: double declaration...

Comment: And use of unitialized variable num.....

Comment: In the 1st line the `num` variable should be initialized to some value before it can be used. Even if that is not the problem, I think the compiler will complain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're declaring the variable twice with `int num`. You don't need to redeclare the variable within the loop, just assign it:

```
int num = 0; // initialized num to 0 here
while (num != 999)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a number between 0 and 99");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    try
    {
        num = Convert.ToInt32(input); // Changed int num to num here
        Console.WriteLine("This is element number " + num + " : " + randNums[num]);
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Data inputted is not between 0 and 99");
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("You chose the secret value, well done!");
```

Answer (score 2):

You have `int num` defined twice in the same scope. Change the name of one of them. The one inside the loop is invalid since you already have one defined.

Alternately you can remove `int` from the inner one if you want to re-assign the same variable. This way it will overwrite it each time with a new value.

Also when you initialize it the first time, be sure to assign it a value.

**Example:**

```
int num = 0;
```

Comment: I want them to be the same thing though.

Comment: @TomCarter, You want them to be the same?  I dont understand that.  That would seem to indicate that you want `num` to always be 0.

Comment: @paqogomez I think he means he wants to reassign it each time through the loop

Comment: That makes a bit more sense.  @TomCarter, if you put `int` in front of a variable name, you are redeclaring the variable.  You dont want to redeclare, you just want to assign the value from input.

Comment: @Antonio makes a good point in the comments.  The first one needs to be set to 0 initially.

Comment: Good call, I added to my answer

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers, you can do this, for example:

```
if (someCondition)
{
     int num = 23;
}
else
{
     int num = 12;
}
```

But you **can't** do this:

```
int num = 12;
if(someCondition)
{
   int num = 23;
}
```

Because all variables has it's own scope, and if you define a variable in outer scope, you can't define a new variable with the same name in the inner-scope.So if you just want to update the value of your variable, you don't need to declare it again, just use a simple assignment.See [`Compiler Error CS0136`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/973aa6bt%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) documentation for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to declare 2 different variables of the same name. Instead of declaring the second one, just use the one you already declared (take off `int`on the second usage).

```
...
    try
    {
        num = Convert.ToInt32(input); // <-- Using existing declaration here
        Console.WriteLine("This is element number " + num + " : " + randNums[num]);
    }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two int variables with the same name. You need to change the other one since you have an int variable for the input that will accept the number assigned by the user, and another int variable responsible for detecting whether the number inputted is 999 or not.